# Calculate light disruption at a certain position

Tags: c++, light

I have no current code for this. I know there are computers programmed to count frequency by counting how many times an object disrupts a light source but what i want to know if there is a way to calculate the exact length/position of where that light is being disrupted. I am sorry if this is not the right website to ask a question like this, if it is not, would anyone know of a great source of where I can ask this question?

Comment: It's unclear why you tagged this with `c++`. There is a [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and an [Electronics StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you can check if your question fits on those sites instead (you can also [search for others](https://stackexchange.com/sites)).

Comment: Alright I will check out the other StackExchange sites, and I thought it may relate to c++ for programming, and sorry for all of that. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it. Have a great one!